# How does Python support this common problem related to run time polymorphism?

Tags: python, polymorphism

I am trying to exectute the below code but I get errors.

```
class base:

    def callme(data):
        print(data)


class A(base):

    def callstream(self):
        B.stream(self)

    def callme(data):
        print("child ", data)


class B:

    def stream(data):
     # below statement doesn't work but I want this to run to achieve run time 
     # polymorphism where method call is not hardcoded to a certain class reference.
     (base)data.callme("streaming data")

     # below statement works but it won't call child class overridden method. I 
     # can use A.callme() to call child class method but then it has to be 
     # hardcoded to A. which kills the purpose. Any class A or B or XYZ which 
     # inherits base call should be able to read stream data from stream class. 
     # How to achive this in Python? SO any class should read the stream data as 
     # long as it inherits from the base class. This will give my stream class a 
     # generic ability to be used by any client class as long as they inherit 
     # base class.
     #base.callme("streaming data")


def main():
    ob = A()

    ob.callstream()


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Which error do you get? In which line?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking. If you're interested in how a derived class can access methods from the base class, you'll want to read up on `super()`.

Comment: I want ob.callstream() to finally invoke callme method of child class..

Comment: I want ob.callstream() to finally invoke callme method of child class..
Here is what should happen.

1. main method calls ob.callstream() method of class A.
2. callstream() method should call B.stream() method of class B
3. Call B stream method calls callme method of base calass using base class reference but it actually contains child class object so base class ref should invoke A.callme as it is its child class.

Comment: Basically all calls to base.callme should invoke A.class me to ahieve run time polymorphism. Problem with python is it doesn't use a class onjetc to call it's method rather uses the class name itself to call it's method from another class. So I cant do base().callme(). I have to write base.callme().

Comment: the expected output is to print "child streaming data"

Answer (score 0):

I got the output you say you're looking for (in a comment rather than the question -- tsk, tsk) with the following code, based on the code in your question:

```
class base:

    def callme(self, data):
        print(data)


class A(base):

    def callstream(self):
        B.stream(self)

    def callme(self, data):
        print("child", data)


class B:
    @classmethod
    def stream(cls, data):
        data.callme("streaming data")


def main():
    ob = A()

    ob.callstream()


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Basically, I just made sure the instance methods had `self` parameters, and since you seem to be using `B.stream()` as a class method, I declared it as such.